# Inserting year with zero

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Is it possible to enter a date with a zero year?
What would the insert clause look like?

I ask, as an application is doing this, see the dump of the date:

```
dt_data: 05/01/00
dump(dt_data): Typ=12 Len=7: 100,100,5,1,1,1,1
to_char(dt_data, 'dd/MM/yyyy'): 00/00/0000
```

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: There was no year zero, at least in the Christian calendar. Probably because zero wasn't introduced to the West until 130 AD :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SQL> create table t1 (c1 date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (date'0000-01-05');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select c1, to_char(c1, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), dump(c1) from t1;

C1                  TO_CHAR(C1
------------------- ----------
DUMP(C1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000-01-05 00:00:00 00/00/0000
Typ=12 Len=7: 100,100,1,5,1,1,1
```

Comment: What is `dump()` results?

Comment: Thanks, but why `(date'0000-01-05 ')` works and `to_date ('01-05-0000', 'dd-MM-yyyy')` does not?

Comment: Balazs, so Oracle allows for year 0? Does it also allow for year -1?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ A `date` type allows the year part to be between -4712 and 9999. `date'-0001-01-01'` works as well.

Comment: @HomerSimpson I tested the above in a `11.2.0.4.180417` because you mentioned `11.2.0.3`, and this is the closest I have. It worked. Then I tested in `12.2.0.1.180417` and `18.2.0.0.0`. There it throws an `ORA-01841` error as expected: `01841, 00000, "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
// *Cause: Illegal year entered
// *Action: Input year in the specified range`

Comment: I tried similar to your code and it inserts a `0000-00-00` "date": https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=34e741243a94e536fbf5b764422b38f1

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, I got all zeros as well  from `TO_CHAR` in the above output. `syyyy` can be used as well to display the sign for the year.

Comment: Seems like Oracle allows for a "year 0", while it shouldn't: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ef549e2b7488fec29876ada882b6be8b It also doesn't distinguish (when displaying) properly `0000-01-01` / `'0000-01-07'` but it does arithmetic between them.

Comment: Oops, I had forgotten it. The ISO standardization has a year 0 indeed ...